# How can I group the yAxis of a HighStock Chart by Month Only Using (Millisecond) Time-Stamps?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a database, where I am getting time-stamps (millisecond) along with price values and trying to plot them on a "HighStock" chart.

I was told to, instead of just letting the exact date show up on the y-axis, have the y-axis show only on a month-by-month basis. The problem is that I have an array of arrays (the format, and the only format I'm aware of, that HighStock accepts) with time-stamps which end up being interpreted by exact date (as I would expect).

I thought about just modifying the time-stamps myself based on month (I already have JavaScript functions that can convert time-stamps to dates and vice versa), but then I would get something like `Monday, Jul 1, 2013 -- Thursday, Aug 1, 2013` etc. Of course, the `Jul 1` or `Aug 1` could be converted to whatever date I grouped by in the time-stamp, but I really would need to take that out entirely and have it say just `Jul` and `Aug`.  I'm sure this is possible, given the never-ending plethora of options HighCharts/HighStock has, but I am out of options on where to look.

With the help of the following sites:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock

And trying things myself, I have learned a bit about what some of the options do, but I am no closer to my original goal.

I have looked in plotOptions, xAxis, and others (where I would think they might be) but I am on the verge of giving up. The documentation on these sites are very helpful, but it is not always clear what they do, or what syntax they expect.

Whether there's an easy way to this with HighCharts/HighStock options using the original time-stamps alone, or whether I need to convert every time-stamp to a date, compare months while adding values together, then re-converting back into a time-stamp, and finding a chart option which omits all but the month and year, I have to get this done. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you need something like an [axis-label-formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter)? Have you tried using this?

Comment: So in general, you have a problem with tickInterval on yAxis and labels / (timestamps are not converted into dates) on ticks.

Comment: @ThoughtfulThighentist Thanks for the help. I see it says the following: `Callback JavaScript function to format the label. The value is given by this.value. Additional properties for this are axis, chart, isFirst and isLast. Defaults to:function(){return this.value;}` I guess my kung-fu isn't strong enough to understand what I'm supposed to do here. I have been struggling with all of the documentation found in HighCharts/HighStock since I have started using it. It's a very impressive plug-in but requires a training course in and of itself.

Comment: @VoidKing - I totally understand. Basically this function is called once for every label value to be put on the chart. `this.value` is the default label to be applied to the chart. Hence, if your labels were `Jul 1` and `Aug 1`, instead of returning `this.value;` you could return `this.value.substring(0,3);` to return the first 3 characters - `Jul` and `Aug`. If this sounds like what you're looking for and you need an example, I can get one going!

Comment: @ThoughtfulThighentist Actually, that sounds exactly like what I'm looking for! Thank you! I might even be able to get a solution going based off of that, alone, but please, if you don't mind, I would love to see your answer, plus you'll get some points out of the deal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example from the [Highcharts API Reference page](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.y).

If you have categories like this, for example:

```
categories: ['Jan 1', 'Feb 1', 'Mar 1', 'Apr 1', 'May 1', 'Jun 1', 'Jul 1', 'Aug 1', 'Sep 1', 'Oct 1', 'Nov 1', 'Dec 1']
```

You can use this type of config for the xAxis label:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan 1', 'Feb 1', 'Mar 1', 'Apr 1', 'May 1', 'Jun 1', 'Jul 1', 'Aug 1', 'Sep 1', 'Oct 1', 'Nov 1', 'Dec 1'],
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return this.value.substring(0,3); // - formatted return value
            //return this.value; // - default return value
        }
    }
},
```

Here's a Fiddle that you can mess around with to show you exactly how it works: [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/79NeT/).